# Elasticsearch-curator - Daily jobs running from unknown source

Tags: elasticsearch, elk, elasticsearch-curator

I'm doing some work on our Elasticseatch cluster. Problem is, I can see from the logs that something from a previous setup is doing a daily run at 10pm to close indices once they are a month old, and this is going to interfere with the new setup.

I've asked around everyone I can think of, but nobody has any knowledge of what's running this scheduled job. I'm assuming it's just some box somewhere running some elasticsearch-curator commands on a cron schedule or similar, but I don't have any idea how to find the source.

Q: Is there any way to find out what machine is sending elasticsearch-curator commands to our Elasticsearch cluster?

Any advice? I'm pretty new to this sort of work, only started in this team a few months ago coming from a help desk background, so my knowledge and understanding of these areas is still limited.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you check the Elasticsearch logs at that time, you may be able to find out the client IP address where those requests are originating from, but otherwise I can't think of any other way to trace them.